# how to turn off the notebook screen only?

Tags: multiple-monitors

due to a fall, the notebook screen broke but remains on with several light streaks. I'm connecting the notebook with an external monitor, so I wanted to be able to turn off the notebook display while using the monitor.

Comment: Does not one of the keys on the notebook top row not do that it would have a small monitor symbol.

Comment: [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/399743/471157) from the Unix & Linux SE site will give you a pretty solid solution, including how to handle reboots 

Comment: thanks @matigo 

xrandr --output eDP-1 --off --output VGA-1 --auto

Answer (score 0):

for my case

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --off --output VGA-1 --auto
```

See more details:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399739/disable-laptop-screen-and-use-only-vga/399743#399743